# Вызов методов инициализации при множественном наследовании

Tags: python

Предположим, у меня есть два класса, имеющих методы `__init__` и третий, наследующий их:

```py
class A:  
    def __init__ (self, x):  
        self.x = x

class B:  
    def __init__ (self, y):  
        self.y = y  

class C (A, B):  
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):  
        A.__init__(self, **kwargs)  
        B.__init__(self, **kwargs)  

obj = C(**{'x': 5, 'y': 10})
#TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y'
```

Можно ли каким-либо образом осуществить инициализацию, не перечисляя вручную все аргументы для двух классов в параметрах `С.__init__`?

Comment: Зачем таки чудные конструкции? Почему не `super().__init__(**kwargs)`?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, а как с помощью super добиться срабатывания обоих родительских инитов? Ну и проблему с лишними аргументами это тоже не решает.

Comment: В родительских классах тоже вызывать `super`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В модуле `inspect` есть функция `getfullargspec`, которая для любой функции возвращает список её аргументов. Нулевым элементом этого списка идёт список обязательных аргументов. Для метода класса в нём первым будет `self`. Соответственно, если для результата `getfullargspec` взять срез `[0][:1]` - то это и будут те имена, которые нужно передать в метод после `self`.

```
from inspect import getfullargspec


def filter_args(all_kwargs, func):
    func_kwargs = getfullargspec(func)[0][1:]

    return {k: v for (k, v) in all_kwargs.items()
            if k in func_kwargs}


class A:  
    def __init__ (self, x):  
        self.x = x

class B:  
    def __init__ (self, y):  
        self.y = y  

class C (A, B):  
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):
        a_kwargs = filter_args(kwargs, A.__init__)
        A.__init__(self, **a_kwargs)
        b_kwargs = filter_args(kwargs, B.__init__)
        B.__init__(self, **b_kwargs)  

obj = C(**{'x': 5, 'y': 10})

print(obj.x)
print(obj.y)
```

Либо можно изменить инициализаторы родительских классов, чтобы они принимали всё, что им передадут, и забирали из этого только то, что им нужно:

```
class A:  
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):  
        self.x = kwargs['x']

class B:  
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):  
        self.y = kwargs['y']

class C (A, B):  
    def __init__ (self, **kwargs):  
        A.__init__(self, **kwargs)  
        B.__init__(self, **kwargs)  

obj = C(**{'x': 5, 'y': 10})

print(obj.x)
print(obj.y)
```